# Receiving selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element message

Tags: java, python-3.x

I am new to the site. I am trying to select/click on elements on http://autotask.net. I have tried to find element using the following methods:

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#HREF_btnPrint > img:nth-child(1)')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/img')

...but it gives me the exception in the Title.

I can find elements fine on the logon page(i.e. 'username' 'password' fields), but once I log in - selenium can't find any elements on the page.

I've only been learning/coding python for a few weeks now and I know nothing about Java. If you need more information, please let me know - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the python syntax, so I will use Java instead. I think there are 2 possible cases, first your driver look into the DOM structure while the page is loading. The other one is the web driver doesn't points at the root of DOM. I usually have the wait method to wait until the page finish loading, and switch to the default content before looking for some elements.

First, I pass both WebDriver, Element id, and Element name through constructor. Then I have `waitUntilReady()` that implement the logic to check the existing of element within specific timeout.

```
    public void waitUntilReady() {
            WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 30);
            waiter.withMessage("\"" + getElementName() + "\" is not ready in 30 seconds")
                    .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
                            /* isReady() returns true if all elements 
                             * that you need to test are available. 
                             * Note that if you have javascript, you 
                             * should have some hidden field to tell 
                             * you that the whole page has loaded. */
                            return isReady();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

as well as switch to default content before find the element

```
WebElement getWebElement() {
    WebElement webElement;
    try {
        getWebDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
        webElement = getWebDriver().findElement(By.id(elementId));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        getLogger().log(Level.SEVERE, "Element id '" + elementId + "' does not exist");
        throw ex;
    }
    return webElement;
}
```

If it doesn't work, you can have `<body id="container">`, then use driver.findElementById("container").findElementById("your target element")

Comment: I am not familiar with Java. I get what you're saying with the <body id='container'> then finding the element byid method. I need the python syntax to find an element within an element.